# Making the printf function of C into Python

Tags: python, c

I wanna make a "Hello, (name)." function in Python by trying to make the C `printf` function.

I want to turn it from this:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print(f"Hello, {name}.")
```

Into this:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
printf("Hello, %s.", name)
```

I started off the function like this and I knew it wasn't going to work because of the second argument:

```
def printf(text, ...):
    print(text)
```

How can I make a properly working printf function like this?

Comment: Why not to use the easy one `print("Hello,", name)`

Comment: Well, I wanna try experimenting the functions from a language to another so that I don't have to interpolate languages altogether but rather make certain functions that I could use later on for a simple language-collaborative program. @Imran

Comment: Seems like a cool project to create a printf function, even if it's not needed, it'd be nice to see how different folks would write it.  And at times, it could be quite handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def printf(text, *args):
    print(text % args)
```

That should do the trick, but perhaps just use an f string like you did in the first example, no need to "reinvent the wheel" right?

Comment: Well, yes, but actually no. I wanna try to make functions, just like what my name says.

Answer (score 0):

there is no printf function in Python, there however is the f string. You used it in one of your examples just go with that its honestly super easy and efficient

Comment: I know there isn't, I just wanna make it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting something like this:

```
name = input("What's your name?")
print("Hello, %s!" % name)
```

You can learn more here: [String Formatting in learnpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting)

Comment: Nah, not really.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rewrite a function at all.
You see:

```py
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Hello,%s."%name) # Basically the same as the printf function.
```

Comment: I want to just for fun, but thanks for showing me this.